# Android-Expandable List

Tags: android

How to add image to expandable list of parent in android. If you click on the parent then image will be changed and after one more click it shows previous image. is it possible? if yes then please give the examples.

thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to update **arrow icon** as shown in below image

use `myExpListView.`[setGroupIndicator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#setGroupIndicator%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

or if you want to set images (as the vehicle images in below image) in the ExpandableListView do set it in adapter layout.

[image]

**UPDATE:** To set the group indicator image on clicking any Group

```
        myExpListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener()
            {  
                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                {
                   //set new image for group indicator here
                    myExpListView.setGroupIndicator(R.drawable.newImage);
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Group clicked", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Good Luck

Comment: Can you please answer what actually you want to change that **arrow icon** **or** the **vehicle image**?

Comment: arrow icon (if you click on group item then list will be expanded and arrow icon is changed like that i want to implement using customized icons that means if you click on the group item then customized icon also changed and one more click list will be compressed and previous icon will be displayed)